# blockUI first-timer, how can I make it run after a button has been clicked?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, blockui, jquery-blockui

I want the blockUI screen to appear once the user has clicked a button to update some entries in the database, but it's been running since the page loads instead, which is useless to me. I want it to run after the user clicks, and to stop when the process has finished.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $.blockUI({ message: '<h2>Loading</h2>' });

</script>
```

I tried to call the function with an OnClientClick event but I'm not sure of what to call exactly, and it either gives me an error or does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It's running since the  page loads because it loads your script in the beginning and so it executes your blockUI and you forget to unblock it so your page remains blocked. To solve this you should call a function when your button click that will block your page until your updates finish in the database and then unblock it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function clicked(){
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h2>Loading</h2>' });
    updateDatabase();
  }

  function updateDatabase(){
    // updating database

    // when the database finish your updates unblock your UI
    $.unblockUI();
  }
</script>

<body>

<button onclick="clicked();">Update Database</button>
</body>
```

i hope this will help you